# Python introspection: how to detect what fields are accessed from a method

Tags: python, methods, properties, introspection

I need to perform some black and dirty magic with Python.

Following my previous question [Lazy data-flow (spreadsheet like) properties with dependencies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340289/lazy-data-flow-spreadsheet-like-properties-with-dependencies-in-python) now I'd like to populate the list of fields a derived property depends on automagically by inspecting the calculate function.

I think I could use `func_code.co_names` attribute, but I'm not very sure if there are some caveats there and the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) does not help much.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `func_code.co_names` is not likely going to help much.  This contains all names that are accessed within the code segment, including global variables, in order of appearance.

```
class Test(object):
    def calc_a(self):
        return self.b + self.c

    def calc_x(self):
        return self.y.a + self.y.b

>>> Test.calc_a.func_code.co_names
('b', 'c')
>>> Test.calc_x.func_code.co_names
('y', 'a', 'b')
```

It is not possible to tell from this array if 'a' and 'b' loaded from 'self' or from 'self.y'.  Generally, the only way to know the access pattern of a bit of code without executing it is to disassemble it.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Test.calc_x)
 23           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (y)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (a)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                0 (y)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                2 (b)
             18 BINARY_ADD          
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

We see that the function loads the 'self' variable (which is always `co_varnames[0]` for a bound function), then from that object loads the attribute 'y' (`co_names[0]`), and then from that object loads the attribute 'a' (`co_names[1]`).  A second stack object is pushed from self.y.b, then the two are added.

Look at the source of dis.py in the standard lib to see how the C Python binary code is disassembled.  Loads of the 0th variable will be important for bound functions.  Another handy point is that the arguments to the function are `co_varnames[:co_argcount]`  (the rest or varnames are locals) and `co_freevars` are variables from an enclosing non-global scope.